# pg_dump vs pg_dumpall? which one to use to database backups?

Tags: postgresql, database-backups

I tried `pg_dump` and then on a separate machine I tried to import the sql and populate the database, I see

```
CREATE TABLE
ERROR:  role "prod" does not exist
CREATE TABLE
ERROR:  role "prod" does not exist
CREATE TABLE
ERROR:  role "prod" does not exist
CREATE TABLE
ERROR:  role "prod" does not exist
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
WARNING:  no privileges could be revoked for "public"
REVOKE
ERROR:  role "postgres" does not exist
ERROR:  role "postgres" does not exist
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "public"
GRANT
```

which means my `user` and `roles` and `grant` information is not in `pg_dump`

On the other hand we have `pg_dumpall`, I read [conversation](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/h49gi3$4ko$1@reversiblemaps.ath.cx), and this does not lead me anywhere?

**Question**
- Which one should I be using for database backups? `pg_dump` or `pg_dumpall`?
- the requirement is that I can take the backup and should be able to import to any machine and it should work just fine.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "* I read conversation, and this does not lead me anywhere*". The manual is pretty clear on what each of the tools does. If you need to export users, then you have to use pg_dumpall.

Comment: This question should be moved to http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The usual process is:

- `pg_dumpall --globals-only` to get users/roles/etc
- `pg_dump -Fc` for each database to get a nice compressed dump suitable for use with `pg_restore`.

Yes, this kind of sucks. I'd really like to teach `pg_dump` to embed `pg_dumpall` output into `-Fc` dumps, but right now unfortunately it doesn't know how so you have to do it yourself.

Up until PostgreSQL 11 there was also a nasty caveat with this approach: Neither `pg_dump`, nor `pg_dumpall` in `--globals-only` mode would dump user access `GRANT`s on `DATABASE`s. So you pretty much had to extract them from the catalogs or filter a `pg_dumpall`. This is fixed in PostgreSQL 11; see the [release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/release-11.html).

> Make pg_dump dump the properties of a database, not just its contents (Haribabu Kommi)
>
> Previously, attributes of the database itself, such as database-level `GRANT`/`REVOKE` permissions and `ALTER DATABASE SET` variable settings, were only dumped by `pg_dumpall`. Now `pg_dump --create` and `pg_restore --create` will restore these database properties in addition to the objects within the database. `pg_dumpall -g` now only dumps role- and tablespace-related attributes. `pg_dumpall`'s complete output (without -g) is unchanged.

---

You should also know about physical backups - `pg_basebackup`, PgBarman and WAL archiving, PITR, etc. These offer much "finer grained" recovery, down to the minute or individual transaction. The downside is that they take up more space, are only restoreable to the same PostgreSQL version on the same platform, and back up all tables in all databases with no ability to exclude anything.

Comment: How to restore globals file? When I try to restore it an error raises: "input file does not appear to be valid archive (too short?)".

Comment: @Umagon Use `psql -f globals.sql`

Comment: @CraigRinger So how do we backup the `GRANT`s on `DATABASE`s

Comment: @BasilMusa `pg_dump --globals-only`

Comment: @CraigRinger You mentioned that neither pg_dump nor pg_dumpall --globalsonly will dump use access GRANT's on DATABASEs. So my question was: "Then how can we backup user GRANTs"

Comment: @BasilMusa Ah, sorry. That's been fixed more recently, I'll revise. Fixed in PostgreSQL 11.

Answer (score 1):

Both commands `pg_dump` and `pg_dumpall` are pretty same. The difference is that (taken from `man pg_dumpall`):

- `pg_dumpall` dumps all databases of a cluster into one script file. It does this by calling pg_dump for each database in the cluster.
- `pg_dumpall` also dumps global objects that are common to all databases, namely database roles, tablespaces, and privilege grants for configuration parameters. `pg_dump` does not save these objects.

[So the easiest way to backup/restore your database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/upgrading.html#UPGRADING-VIA-PGDUMPALL) (even between major versions) is:

```
pg_dumpall -p 5432 | psql -d postgres -p 5433
```

You need to provide `postgres` as default database (-d flag), because on a new server, probably, you have only it.