# improperly importing sql file in postgres cli

Tags: database, postgresql, command-line-interface

I have a question about importing a sql file to postgres CLI. I may have been improperly importing my file or either I may have some User or Database privilege?!? issue. Anyways, these are just my hunches. I am trying to pinpoint the cause of this message after importing a sql file.

The message that I get is:

> No relations found.

The steps I did to get into Postgres are:

I typed in:

- `sudo -i -u postgres`
- `psql`
- then i created a new role, altered the role permission
- and then created a new database as well
- i got all my commands from this site http://blog.jasonmeridth.com/posts/postgresql-command-line-cheat-sheet/
- last step was I imported a sql file by typing:
- `psql -d db_name_dev -U username_dev -f /www/dbexport.sql`

Now when I go inside the database I created "db_name_dev" by typing
`psql db_name_dev` and check to see any content imported by typing `\dt`

I get

> No relations found.

here is also a table and role list from my command line..

http://screencast.com/t/8ZMqBLNRb

I'm thinking my database might also have some access privilege issue..

also here is an additional issue i ran into.. hope this helps..
http://screencast.com/t/BJy0ZjrALm6h

thanks,

any feedback would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so after a few research and readings, i found out my .sql file was empty.. here are some links ive read and learnt more about pg_dump command dbforums.com/showthread.php?1646161-Postgresql-Restores and [pg_dump vs pg_dumpall? which one to use to database backups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618627/pg-dump-vs-pg-dumpall-which-one-to-use-to-database-backups)